# Problems with the control design

Tags: linux, bash

Good evening (or day. Whichever)! I ran into a problem while writing a bash script. I have the code

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "Available options:"
echo "1. text"
echo "2. exit"
read var1
echo

if [[$var -ge 0]]; then
   echo "hello world"
elif [[$var -ge 1]]; then
     echo "good bye"
else
    echo "error"
fi
```

and all the time it puts the emphasis on the operator

```
./proba3.sh: line 9: [[: command not found
./proba3.sh: line 11: [[: command not found
```

I tried many variations of the branching operation, but still get the same error. I will be very glad for advice or hints on how to fix this error. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

1. You need spaces inside the brackets.
2. Also you misspelled the variable name.
3. Finally, you should probably test for equality not `ge`

Fixed:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "Available options:"
echo "1. text"
echo "2. exit"
read var
echo

if [[ $var -eq 1 ]]; then
   echo "hello world"
elif [[ $var -eq 2 ]]; then
     echo "good bye"
else
    echo "error"
fi
```